# Detecting image collision within a zoomed scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, intersection, layer

I have an image, call it imageA. I add it to a scrollView, everything works... I can pan/zoom etc etc. I add a second image, call it imageB to the scrollView.

Now I zoom into the images and that works well too.

Now I writing a method to detect when I touch the imageB. I use these code snipits to detect imageB hit.

```
func zapSelectedMask(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.state == .began){
        let zapLocation = sender.location(in: imageA.view)
        zeroInOnmasks(XCord: zapLocation.x, YCord: zapLocation.y)
    }
}

func zeroInOnmasks(XCord: CGFloat, YCord:CGFloat) -> Bool {
  let zeroIn = CGRect(x: XCord, y: YCord, width: 4, height: 4)
  var rectIndex = 0
  matchIndex = nil
  for rect2Inspect in self.imageALayers {
        let lookin = zeroIn.intersection(rect2Inspect.frame)
        if (lookin.width > 0.0 && lookin.height  > 0.0) {
            print("zeroInOnmasks matched")
```

It works unless I zoom in or out in which case my reference to the imageBs contained in the self.imageALayers are not correct. The imageB frames have of course changed.
    Now I print out the frames here ...

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    self.imageA.layer.sublayers?.forEach { print("view4zoom \($0.frame)") }
    return self.image2P
}
```

I find the old frame, not the zoomed in one... how to get the zoomed frame sizes so I may detect a collision?